# Read Resources without \r and \n

Tags: c#, resources

In a Resource-File in my WPF-Application I have a longer SQL-Statement for the creation of a `Database` while runtime. If I try to read the statement with `string command = DataResources.CreateDbCommand` I can get it, but there are several `\r` and `\n` in the command and I can not execute it.

How can I read a `string` from my resource-file without `\r` and `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the \r \n are end or beginning you can just trim them with

```
command = command.Trim();
```

or you can remove them from anywhere in the string before executing the command

```
command = command.Replace("\r\n", " "); //replace with a space character
command = command.Replace("\r\n", ""); //remove them without adding anything
```